# Regex first match

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I have dataframe and i wand to extract some localisation on the text using regex. I have to extract three values and create three new columns. I can't match the first occurrence in the text. I must always take the locations before the dashes in text exemple.

```
df["Auto localisation 1"]=df["Description"].str.extract(r"Localisation[\s]*:([^\n].*)\n")
df["Auto localisation 2"]=df["Description"].str.extract("Localisation[\s]*:.*\n([^_\n]*)\n[^\n]*\n_+")
df["Auto localisation 3"]=df["Description"].str.extract("Localisation[\s]*:.*\n[^_\n]*\n([^\n_]*)\n")
```

exemple of strong texttext is below:

```
reference de piece
 27.10.2020 08:49:49 JEAN BAPTISTE DAIGREMONT (ijuplo) Tél. 00
 Localisation:TRAIN
 PRINCIPAL GAUCHE
 ______________________________
 Non-conformité 0001 :
 Type de non-conf. : Absence couleur/peinture, pigmentation

 VISITE AVION AVANT PEINTURE

 Nous constatons qu'il manque  du bleu
 metallo sur les cosses des tresses de masses ainsi
 que du gris sous les rivets suite à notre demande
 de reprise.
 Localisation : Sous les trappes "porte feuille
 G/D"
 Voir exemple en PJ.
 Flamme toujours en place.

 Demandons interventions pour remise en état.
 ______________________________
 Moment de Détection: Lors de l'inspection
```

ouput expected:

```
Auto localisation 1=TRAIN
Auto localisation 2=GAUCHE
Auto localisation 3=(empty) because in this exemple there is not localisation 3
```

My code give as result:

```
Auto localisation 1=TRAIN
Auto localisation 2=GAUCHE
Auto localisation 3=Voir exemple en PJ
```

How can result this problem? thks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your 3 patterns, you can start the match from the start of the string, and do not cross matching lines that either start with Localisation: or only underscores using a negative lookahead.

```
\A(?:(?![^\S\n]*Localisation:|[^\S\n]*_+\n).*\n)*[^\S\n]*Localisation[\s]*:([^\n].*)\n
\A(?:(?![^\S\n]*Localisation:|[^\S\n]*_+\n).*\n)*[^\S\n]*Localisation[\s]*:.*\n([^_\n]*)\n[^\n]*\n
\A(?:(?![^\S\n]*Localisation:|[^\S\n]*_+\n).*\n)*[^\S\n]*Localisation[\s]*:.*\n[^_\n]*\n([^\n_]*)\n
```

[Regex demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/3EWeCh/1) | [Regex demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/hVi9Ze/1) | [Regex demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/EUjOxO/1)

Or with a single regex and 3 named capture groups:

```
\A(?:(?![^\S\n]*Localisation:|[^\S\n]*_+\n).*\n)*[^\S\n]*Localisation\s*:(?P<Auto_localisation_1>[^\n].*)(?:\n[^\S\n]*(?!Localisation:)(?P<Auto_localisation_2>[^\s_].*)(?:\n[^\S\n]*(?!Localisation:)(?P<Auto_localisation_3>[^\s_].*))?)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XQSPMK/1)